# C recursion does not recurse

Tags: c, function, recursion

My search did not yield any results. Also, my english is pretty bad, sorry for that.

So my program should do this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYbJs.png]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

float rec();

int main()
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
  int w;
  scanf("%d",&w);
  printf("%f",rec(w));
  return 0;
}

float rec(n)
{
  if (n<1)
  {
    printf("Error");
  }
  else if (n==1)
  {
    return 6;
  }
  else if (n>1)
  {
    return 1/2*rec(n-1)+4;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

When the input is 1 it outputs 6, as it is supposed to.

When the input is <1 it outputs "Error0,000000".

When the input is >1 it only outputs the number that is added in

```
return 1/2*rec(n-1)+4;
```

In this case, it outputs 4. Why? Is rec(n-1) == 0?

My questions are:

1. Why won't it work?
2. How do i make it output "Error" instead of "Error0,000000" when the input is <1?

Comment: @MarcB he actually returns 0 in that case, as the functions goes through to the very end

Comment: ah yeah. the bad indentation threw me off...

Comment: Your function prototype is `float rec();` which takes no arguments. You should declare it as `float rec(int);` (or whatever datatype suits)

Comment: Also you should pick a book and look how to write function interfaces in modern C. Both, your prototype and definition for `rec` should have the type of the parameter,

Comment: @Olipro, no an empty list in a function *declaration* in C actually means that the function may receive any number and type of parameters.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, you are correct. However, C11 defines this as an obsolescent feature and really one that you should avoid using as a matter of best practice.

Comment: 1. Because 1/2 with ints is 0, so rec(n-1) gets multiplied with 0 and lastly 4 is added. Use parantheses and/or other data types. 2. Since you return 0 from rec in this case and printf the result, this is what you get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer division!

Here,

```
return 1/2*rec(n-1)+4;
```

`1/2` will yields `0` due to integer division. So it's always going to be `4` as the final result.

Instead you can do:

```
return 1.0/2*rec(n-1)+4;
```

which will make sure the computation happens as `double`.

You might also simply want to add `return 0`; in the `if (n<1)` case and change the function definitio to:

```
float rec(int n) {... }
```

If you don't specify a *type* for `n`, it defaults to `int` in pre-C99. But this is no longer the case in C99 and C11.

Comment: Since the division has an exactly representable result, why not just say `0.5*rec(n-1)+4;`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Of course. There are more than one way to skin a cat. But I don't see any obvious advantage of using `0.5`. A decent compiler would compute it at compile-time anyway.

Comment: To be sure, the two variations mean the same thing, and probably (but not necessarily) the compiler will produce the same code for the two.  But the version with `0.5` is easier to read and understand, and not much prone to a clueless junior programmer later changing it back to the original, integer division form.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is mainly a type issue: try

```
return 1.0/2.0*rec(n-1)+4
```

to tell the compiler, that you want floating point arithmetic during the calculation. Otherwise, an integer division is performed and casted to float *afterwards*.

Fwiw: You wouldn't use a recursion for this, an iteration would fully suffice, be better understandable, perform better and needed less resources than the recursive version in c.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to give you the answer of the second question.

You need a buffer for the return value of rec.

So,

```
float answer = rec(w);
if (NOTHING_HAPPENED)
    print("%f", answer);
```

This will work!

Answer (score 0):

2. In the case where n<1, you printf "Error" from the called routine, and then return 0 to be printf'd (as a float) in main. Don't do that ;-)

Personally, I'd check for the original being <1 in main as an alternative to calling rec() and printf.

1. This would be easier to answer if you'd tell us what it's supposed to produce.

However, I suspect your problem is related to rec() taking an integer argument, but returning a float. If you want recursive functions to behave sanely, their argument and return type should match.  Quite likely your issue is that at some point you pass a decimal fraction that is approximately equal to 1, which does not get converted to 1 by the implicit type conversion.